# bash "command not found" - is my PATH wrong

Tags: bash

I'm using bash for the first time.  Wrote a code that is supposed to take "stats" as a command, but whenever I use "stats" in my command lines I kept getting the following error:

```
bash: stats: command not found
```

I googled around and a lot of people are saying this error is usually associated with PATH problems.  Running "echo $PATH" yields the following results:

```
/bin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/apps/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/nfs/stak/students/z/myname/bin:.
```

I made sure my program started with

```
#!/bin/bash
```

Is my PATH wrong?  If so, how do I fix it?  If not, any suggestions on what else I should look into?  Thank you all for your time and help.

Comment: Does the command `stats` actually exist? don't you mean `stat` (without `s`) instead?

Comment: The name of the script is called stats

Comment: Where is the script located? (Run `pwd`). Does it have executable permissions? (Run `ls -al` in the folder the script exists).

Comment: after running pwd the output says /nfs/stak/students/z/myname/344.  after runnin ls -al it displays the script with "-rw-rw----" not sure what that means

Comment: Use `chmod +x ./stats` and run your script with `./stats`.

Comment: If it's your 'stats' script -- it means it is **not executable**. `chmod 0755 statsfilename` and then execute it with `./statsfilename` (in the current directory) or `/absolute/path/to/the/file`.

Comment: I tried both methods above and kept getting the ": No such file or directory" message, which is a bit confusing because when I type "ls" it shows me that a file named "stats" IS in the directory.

Comment: Does the script have Windows/DOS-style line endings? Try printing it with `cat -vet stats`, and see if the first line is "#!/bin/bash^M$" (DOS-style, with a carriage return, indicated by "^M", before the linefeed) or just "#!/bin/bash$" (no "^M" = no carriage return = unix-style line endings, which is what you want).

Comment: Thank you!  That was the problem!  I then googled how to remove ^M and my program works just fine now.  Can you make this into an answer so I can check it? Thank you SO much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `PATH` looks reasonable. `PATH` problems are a common source of errors like this, but not the only one.

The error message ": No such file or directory" suggests that the script file has DOS/Windows-style line endings (consisting of a carriage return followed by linefeed) instead of unix-style (just linefeed). Unix programs (including shells) tend to mistake the carriage return for part of the line, causing massive confusion.

In this instance, it sees the shebang line as "#!/bin/bash^M" (where "^M" indicates the carriage return), goes looking for an interpreter named "/bin/bash^M", can't find it, and prints something like "/bin/bash^M: No such file or directory". Since the carriage return makes the terminal return to the beginning of the line, ": No such file or directory" gets printed on top of the "/bin/bash" part, so it's all you see.

If you have the `dos2unix` program, you can use that to convert to unix-style line endings; if not, there are a variety of alternate conversion tools. But you should also figure out why the file has Windows/DOS format: did you edit it with a Windows editor, or something like that? Whatever caused it, you should make sure it doesn't happen again, because Windows/DOS format files will cause problems with most unix programs.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a PATH problem, it might be a permission problem. Some things to try.

1) If stats is not in your current directory, change directory (cd) to the directory where stats is and do

```
bash stats
```

If stats executes correctly, then you know at least that the script is OK. Otherwise, look at the script itself.

2) Try to execute the script with

```
./stats
```

If this gives

```
bash: ./stats: Permission denied
```

Then you have a permission problem. Do a

```
chmod a+rx stats
```

and retry. Note: a+rx is perhaps a bit wide; some may suggest

```
chmod 755 stats
```

is a better choice. Hint: from the comments, I see that this is one of your problems.

3) From the name of the directory, I get the impression that the file is on NFS. It might therefore be mounted as 'noexec', meaning that you cannot execute any files from that mount. You might try:

```
cp stats /tmp
chmod 700 /tmp/stats
/tmp/stats
```

4) Check the full path name for stats. If you are still in the same directory as stats, try

```
pwd
```

Check if this directory is present in the PATH. If not, add it.

```
export PATH=$PATH:/nfs/stak/students/z/myname/344
```

and try stats again.